# Connecting Apple monitor to Dell latitude E6540

Tags: video-adapter

I have an Apple monitor with mini DisplayPort and a Dell laptop E6540 that I want to connect. The Dell provides output for HDMI and VGA, its docking station also provides DVI.

Although I have found adapters for miniDP to DVI or VGA (e.g., to connect a Mac to a projector) I have not been able to find the inverse adapter (DVI, VGA or HDMI to miniDP).

Does someone know where I can find such adapters?

Comment: Your terminology appears to be partly back-to-front. I've attempted to turn this round for you, but please feel free to re-edit if you feel I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping down from DisplayPort to DVI or VGA is a relatively simple & cheap task.

Unfortunately, going the other way is not so simple... & certainly not so cheap.

I've managed to find these 2 examples of DVI - > DisplayPort adapters, though for the prices you could just about buy a new monitor instead.

I would also be very, very certain that the Apple monitor is, in fact DisplayPort & not Thunderbolt. The connectors look the same & you didn't specify the model in your question.

http://www.startech.com/uk/AV/Converters/Video/DVI-to-DisplayPort-Adapter-with-Audio~DVI2DPA

[http://www.amazon.com/AT-DP400-Displayport-Converter-Designed-Convert/dp/B003CWEXWO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CWEXWO)